# "Доступ запрещён!" при подключении картинок в 1C Bitrix

Tags: битрикс, 1с, битрикс24

Проблема такая, сайт на 1C Bitrix. Есть папка local, в ней папка templates(шаблоны). И там создал шаблон `.default`. При подключении картинок на главной странице сайта с помощью тегов img, из папки .default/images, происходит ошибка. Если посмотреть в консоль разработчика(вкладка network), видно что возвращается ошибка 403, и в preview - `Доступ запрещён!`. Если изменить имя папки `.default` на `default` то картинки подключаются нормально. Может кто-то знает что делать? В качестве сервера использую - openserver, OS - windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях не смог уточнить, Апач или чистый nginx используете на OpenServer?

Если nginx, то у него очень много противоречащих правил, которые можно увидеть в логах. Можно взять готовый конфиг для битрикс + nginx.

Ну, и знаете, для полноты ответа, напишу что нибудь про установку прав на доступ к файлам. Я правда, так и не знаю, Апач или чистый nginx у вас в этом вопросе. Но все-таки, подробнее

Установить права на доступ в админке "Рабочий стол-Контент-Структура сайта-Файлы и папки-local-templates-.default-images" в строке браузера будет ссылка типа "bitrix/admin/fileman_access.php?"

Из установленных прав доступа сформируются BX_*_PERMISSIONS, используя которые можно програмно записать файл .htaccess в папку с изображениями с директивой "allow from All".

```
if(!defined("BX_FILE_PERMISSIONS"))
    define("BX_FILE_PERMISSIONS", 0644);
if(!defined("BX_DIR_PERMISSIONS"))
    define("BX_DIR_PERMISSIONS", 0755);

$DIR_NAME = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/local/templates/.default/images";

$ht_name = $DIR_NAME.".htaccess";
if(!file_exists($ht_name))
{
    $fp = fopen($ht_name, "w");
    if($fp)
    {
        fwrite($fp, "allow from All");
        fclose($fp);
        @chmod($ht_name, BX_FILE_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня стоит apache.

Comment: не помогло, тут дело не в bitrix а в apache, может есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: Попробовал nginx - вот лог : bitrix.mini: 127.0.0.1 [08/Nov/2019:13:09:39 +0300] "GET /local/templates/.default/images/img3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "http://bitrix.mini/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Мне немного неудобно настаивать на другой WAMP/OS, бывает, что попросту, бываает достаточно последовательно "разрешить" доступ из OS, из Админки битрикс, из файла htaccess для данного каталога. Не забывать фиксировать, что изменилось.

Comment: Пробовал, это происходит на уровне apache и nginx, пробовал даже не битрикс а просто сайт, подключать файл из папки .default не получается, и из любой папки имя которой начинается с . не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть ситуацию поможет прояснить вот эта часть документации Битрикса ("Как система ищет шаблон"):
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2829&LESSON_PATH=3913.4565.2829#template_search

В ней рассказывается, что в Битриксе применяется следующий алгоритм поиска подходящего шаблона для компонента:

> Если используется шаблон сайта из папки \local , то система сначала
> ищет шаблон компонента в папке
> /local/templates/текущий_шаблон_сайта/components/. Если там шаблон не
> найден, то берётся папка /local/templates/.default/components/. Если
> шаблон найден, то поиск прекращается. Если используется шаблон сайта
> из папки /bitrix/templates/, то берется папка
> /bitrix/templates/текущий_шаблон_сайта/components/. В этой папке в
> пути /пространство_имен_компонента/название_компонента/ проверяется
> последовательно наличие файла или папки с именем шаблона. Если таковых
> нет, то проверяется наличие файла имя_шаблона.ext, где в качестве ext
> берутся последовательно все доступные расширения всех установленых на
> сайте движков шаблонизации. Если шаблон найден, то алгоритм
> завершается. Если на шаге 1 шаблон не найден, то берется папка
> /bitrix/templates/.default/components/. И применяется алгоритм,
> описанный в шаге 1. Если шаблон найден, то алгоритм завершается. Если
> на шаге 2 шаблон не найден, то производится поиск среди системных
> (т.е. поставляемых с компонентом) шаблонов. Особенности поиска:
>
> Если имя шаблона не задано, то ищется шаблон с именем .default. Если
> шаблон задан именем папки, то в случае простого компонента в этой
> папке ищется файл template.ext, а в случае комплексного -
> название_страницы.ext. Расширение ext сначала принимается равным php,
> а затем расширениям других доступных на сайте движков шаблонизации.
>
> Например, требуется показать компонент bitrix:catalog.list с помощью
> шаблона table. Пусть на сайте, кроме стандартного движка шаблонизации
> (файлы с расширением php), доступен так же движок Smarty (файлы с
> расширением tpl). Система проверит сначала папку
> /local/templates/текущий_шаблон_сайта/components/bitrix/catalog.list/
> на наличие файла или папки с именем table. Если таковых нет, система
> проверит эту же папку на наличие файлов table.php и table.tpl. Если
> ничего не найдено, система изучит папки
> /bitrix/templates/.default/components/bitrix/catalog.list/ и
> /bitrix/components/bitrix/catalog.list/templates/.
>
> Если папка компонента найдена, в этой папке сначала ищется файл
> template.php, и если этот файл не найден, то ищется template.tpl. Если
> шаблон задан в виде table/template.php, то сразу берется указанный
> файл.
>
> Если простой компонент вызывается в составе комплексного, то шаблон
> простого компонента сначала ищется в составе шаблона комплексного
> компонента, а потом (если не найден) в собственных шаблонах. Чтобы это
> правило работало, при вызове простых компонентов в составе
> комплексного не забывайте указывать четвертым параметром переменную
> $component, указывающую на родительский компонент. Т.е. код вызова
> простого компонента должен иметь вид:
>
> $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("custom:catalog.element", "",
> array(...), $component); Примечание: В одной папке (например,
> /bitrix/templates/текущий_шаблон_сайта/components/) есть шаблоны двух
> компонентов, комплексного и простого:
>
> catalog (комплексный, в котором есть еще простой catalog.section)
> catalog.section (простой) По условиям работы сайта необходимо чтобы
> для двух вхождений catalog.section использовался один единственный
> шаблон. В этом случае нужно, чтобы этот шаблон имел имя, отличное от
> .default, иначе он не будет подхвачен.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

В настройках по умолчанию Apache файлы начинающиеся с точки запрещены. Это сделано для того, чтоб никто не мог посмотреть `.htaccess` и подобные.

Ищите вот это в конфиге, чтоб отключить. Но не торопитесь.

```
<LocationMatch "/\.(?!well-known)">
Require all denied
</LocationMatch>
```

Правильное решение для Вас это хранить файлы в папке для файлов - создайте assets или static в корне сайта. В первую очередь показывать миру что у вас там Битрикс и как он расположен не безопасно. Да и пути больно длинные и не относительные. Во вторых тут иногда возможно скачать php файлы с исходником сайта.

Если очень хочется, то добавьте в Апач `<Location>` с настройками на разрешение доступа именно к папке с картинками.